# how to delete a whitespace at the front of filenames while leaving other whitespace untouched in 3000 files in windows 10

Tags: whitespace

I have several thousand photos that somehow got a whitespace in the front of the name. I need to delete the leading whitspace while leaving the space in the actual names. 
Example
""Alaska 2018 0016     ("" represents a blank space) needs to be
Alaska 2018 0016

Comment: You can do it using built-in batch rename function in FreeCommander, for example, in Windows. It may depends on your OS.

Comment: You could write a program to loop through all files in the directory and trim the whitespace. If using C#, the Trim() method will remove all leading and trailing spaces but not spaces within a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with WindowsPowerShell

This is an example from https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#rename_filename_explorer

To make file names shorter, or trim part of the names by an N number of characters, use this command syntax and press Enter:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-N) + $_.Extension}
```

And your command will be

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring(1,$_.BaseName.length) + $_.Extension}
```

So you can delete whitespace

Comment: It could be dangerous in case not all files have exactly one space at the beginning. May be some have been already renamed. It is better to use Regex to capture only space-beginning names.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'd recommend to use user-friendly [FreeCommander](https://freecommander.com) and use its internal renaming instrument.

1. Copy all your files to rename in some folder.
2. Open FreeCommander and go to the folder.
3. Press Alt + F7 and Enter (search all files in the folder and
   subfolders)
4. Press Ctrl + E (take all found files and subfolders to a separate tab)
5. Press * (select all files) and Ctrl + M (batch rename)
6. Go to the group **Find and Replace** and click **Use Regex**
   checkbox (or similar by meaning in your language), then in the field **Find** type `^/s+` (Regex to capture the left padding spaces only), the field **Replace to** leave empty (to delete those spaces).
7. Click **Rename** button.

That's all, your files will be trimmed from the beginning only where are spaces.